# Jbutton is not registering on click (Server Client Setup)

Tags: java, server, client

So While making this small game I redid it twice first to get the server set up and another to take constants out of an interface class and put them into the client, which I assume is alright. **My main problem is** when both clients are up when player 1 (which it is currently implemented for atm) tries to click "Spam to Win!" the code does not fire off. Thus all buttons do nothing. Why is it that they won't trigger. I have called actionListener correctly and have even tried making the button static and non static.

This is the Server which is not done but does the job to currently connect 2 people to 1 server.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server extends JFrame
{
    public static Socket player1;
    public static Scanner player1Input;
    public static PrintWriter player1Output;
    public static Socket player2;
    public static Scanner player2Input;
    public static PrintWriter player2Output;
    public static ServerSocket server;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    final int SBAP_PORT = 8888;
    server = new ServerSocket(SBAP_PORT);
    //Frame
    Server frame = new Server();
    System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

    //Player1
    player1 = server.accept();
    System.out.println("Player 1 has joined."); 

    //input/Output for player 1
    player1Input = new Scanner (player1.getInputStream());
    player1Output = new PrintWriter (player1.getOutputStream());

    //Label player 1
    player1Output.println(1);
    player1Output.flush();
    System.out.println("Waiting for player 2 to connect...");

    //Player1
    player2 = server.accept();
    System.out.println("Player 2 has joined."); 

    //input/Output for player 1
    player2Input = new Scanner (player2.getInputStream());
    player2Output = new PrintWriter (player2.getOutputStream());

    //Label player 1
    player2Output.println(2);
    player2Output.flush();
    System.out.println("Both players have connected.");
}

public Server()
{
    //Frame
    JTextArea jtaLog = new JTextArea();   

    // Create a scroll pane to hold text area
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jtaLog);

    // Add the scroll pane to the frame
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(450, 300);
    setTitle("Server");
    setVisible(true);
}

public void run() 
{
while (true) 
  {
      if(isWon() == 1)
      {

      }
      else if(isWon() == 2)
      {

      }
      else 
      {

      }
  }
}

/** Total clicks to win the game */
private int isWon() 
{
    if(player1Input.equals("WinP1"))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(player2Input.equals("WinP2"))
    {
        return 2;
    }
    return 3;
}
}
```

This is the Client which is a standard that i generated for both players which has a Title bar, Status bar, Disadvantage button, Spam button, and Advantage button.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client extends JApplet implements Runnable
{
    private static final JButton MainClick = new JButton("Spam to win!");
    private static final JButton Advantage = new JButton("Spend 25 " + "clicks for " + "advantages");
    private static final JButton Disadvantage = new JButton("Spend 25 " + "clicks to " + "sabotage " + "your " + "opponent");

    // Starting Value of clicks for player 1
    public int player1Amount = 0;
    // Starting Value of clicks for player 2
    public int player2Amount = 0;
    // Multi-click for Player 1
    public boolean multiclicksP1 = false;
    // Multi-click for Player 2
    public boolean multiclicksP2 = false;
    // 2for1 for Player 1
    public boolean player1TwoForOne = false;
    // 2for1 count for Player 1
    public int player1TwoForOneCount = 0;
    // 2for1 timer
    public Thread timer = new Thread();
    // Enable Countdown for timer
    public boolean countDown = false;
    // Time
    public int time;

    // Creates a random number between 1-4
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomNum1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
    int randomNum2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
    int ranNUmOfClicks = randomGenerator.nextInt(50) + 25;

    // Create and initialize a title label and status label
    private JLabel jlblTitle = new JLabel();
    private JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel();

    // Input and output streams from/to server
    private Scanner fromServer;
    private PrintWriter toServer;

    // Continue to play?
    private boolean continueToPlay = true;

    // Indicate if it runs as application
    private boolean isStandAlone = true;    

    // Host name or ip
    private String host = "localhost";

    /** Initialize UI */
    public void init() 
    {
        // Panel p to hold game
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        // Set properties for labels and borders for labels and panel
        p.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        jlblTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        jlblTitle.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 16));
        jlblTitle.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        jlblStatus.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
        // Place the panel and the labels to the applet
        add(jlblTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(MainClick, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(Advantage, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(Disadvantage, BorderLayout.WEST);
        MainClick.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        Advantage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
        Disadvantage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));

        // Connect to the server
        connectToServer();
    }
    private void connectToServer() 
    {
        try 
        {
          // Create a socket to connect to the server
          Socket socket;
          if (isStandAlone)
            socket = new Socket(host, 8888);
          else
            socket = new Socket(getCodeBase().getHost(), 8000);

          // Create an input stream to receive data from the server
          fromServer = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());

          // Create an output stream to send data to the server
          toServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
          System.err.println(ex);
        }

        // Control the game on a separate thread
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() 
      {
        try 
        {
          // Get notification from the server
          int player = fromServer.nextInt();
          // Am I player 1 or 2?
          if (player == 1) 
          {
            jlblTitle.setText("Player 1 click for your life!" + " Your Clicks: " + player1Amount);
            jlblStatus.setText("Waiting for player 2 to join.");
            // Receive startup notification from the server
            fromServer.nextInt(); // Whatever read is ignored
            // The other player has joined
            jlblStatus.setText("Player 2 has joined. Now Click!");
            MainClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                {
                    //String clicked = event.toString();
                    if(multiclicksP1 == true)
                    {
                        //System.out.println("I'm on!"); //Debug
                        player1Amount = player1Amount + 2;
                        jlblTitle.setText("Player 1 click for your life!" + " Your Clicks: " + player1Amount);
                    }
                    else
                    player1Amount++;
                    jlblTitle.setText("Player 1 click for your life!" + " Your Clicks: " + player1Amount);
                    //System.out.println(player1Amount); //Debug
                }
            }); 
            Advantage.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Button Clicked");
                    //System.out.println("Starting random number: " + randomNum1);
                    if(player1Amount >= 25)
                        {
                            randomNum1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
                            //System.out.println("New random number before choosing: " + randomNum1);
                            player1Amount = player1Amount - 25;
                            if(randomNum1 == 1)
                            {                   
                                multiclicksP1 = true;
                                jlblStatus.setText("Clicks are now worth 2 clicks!");
                                jlblTitle.setText("Player 1 click for your life!" + " Your Clicks: " + player1Amount);
                                randomNum1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
                                //System.out.println("New random number after choosing: " + randomNum1);
                            }
                            if(randomNum1 == 2)
                            {
                                jlblStatus.setText(ranNUmOfClicks + " Clicks were added!");
                                jlblTitle.setText("Player 1 click for your life!" + " Your Clicks: " + player1Amount);
                                player1Amount = player1Amount + ranNUmOfClicks;
                                ranNUmOfClicks = randomGenerator.nextInt(25) + 25;
                                //System.out.println("New random number after adding: " + ranNUmOfClicks);
                            }
                            if(randomNum1 == 3)
                            {
                                jlblStatus.setText("Your opponents clicks wil now slightly help you for a limited time!");
                                player1TwoForOne = true;
                            }
                            if(randomNum1 == 4)
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            jlblStatus.setText("You don't have 25 clicks to spend!");
                        }
                    }
            });
            Disadvantage.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Button Clicked");
                    if(player1Amount >= 25)
                    {

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        jlblStatus.setText("You don't have 25 clicks to spend!");
                    }
                }
            }); 
            }           
          else if (player == 2) 
          {
            jlblTitle.setText("Player 2 click for your life!" + " Your Clicks: " + player2Amount);
            jlblStatus.setText("Now Click!");
            JButton MainClick = new JButton("Spam to win!");
            add(MainClick, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            MainClick.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
            JButton Advantage = new JButton("Spend 25 " + "clicks for " + "advantages");
            add(Advantage, BorderLayout.EAST);
            Advantage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
            JButton Disadvantage = new JButton("Spend 25 " + "clicks to " + "sabotage " + "your " + "opponent");
            add(Disadvantage, BorderLayout.WEST);
            Disadvantage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
            // Receive startup notification from the server
            fromServer.nextInt(); // Whatever read is ignored
            // The other player has joined    
            /*if(countDown == true)
            {
                for(int time = 8; time >= 0; time--)
                {
                    try {
                        timer.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println(time);
                    if(time == 0)
                    {
                        player1TwoForOne = false;
                    }
                }
            }*/
            MainClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                    {
                        if(player1TwoForOne = true)
                        {
                            //countDown = true;
                            player1TwoForOneCount++;
                            System.out.println(player1TwoForOneCount);
                            if(player1TwoForOneCount == 2)
                            {
                                player1Amount = player1Amount + 1;
                                player1TwoForOneCount = 0;
                            }
                            if (time == 0)
                            {
                                countDown = false;
                            }
                        }

                        if(multiclicksP2 == true)
                        {
                            //System.out.println("I'm on!"); //Debug
                            player2Amount = player2Amount + 2;
                            jlblTitle.setText("Player 2 click for your life!" + " Your Clicks: " + player2Amount);
                        }
                        else
                        player2Amount++;
                        jlblTitle.setText("Player 2 click for your life!" + " Your Clicks: " + player2Amount);
                    }
                }); 
                Advantage.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                    {
                        //System.out.println("Starting random number: " + randomNum2);
                        if(player2Amount >= 25)
                        {
                            randomNum2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
                            //System.out.println("New random number before choosing: " + randomNum2);
                            player2Amount = player2Amount - 25;
                            if(randomNum2 == 1)
                            {
                                multiclicksP2 = true;
                                jlblStatus.setText("Clicks are now worth 2 clicks!");
                                jlblTitle.setText("Player 2 click for your life!" + " Your Clicks: " + player2Amount);
                                randomNum2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(4) + 1;
                                //System.out.println("New random number after choosing: " + randomNum2);
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            jlblStatus.setText("You don't have 25 clicks to spend!");
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                Disadvantage.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                    {
                        if(player2Amount >= 25)
                        {

                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            jlblStatus.setText("You don't have 25 clicks to spend!");
                        }
                    }
                });             
          }

          // Continue to play
          while (continueToPlay) 
          {
            int status = fromServer.nextInt();
            continueToPlay = false;
            if (player == 1) 
            {
                if(player1Amount >= 200)
                {
                    toServer.write(1);
                }
            }
            else if (player == 2) 
            {
                if(player2Amount >= 200)
                {
                    toServer.write(2);
                }
            }
            //else if (status == PLAYER1_WON)
            {
                if(player == 1)
                {
                    jlblTitle.setText("Congrats Player 1 you've out click Player 2!");
                }
                if(player == 2)
                {
                    jlblTitle.setText("Player 1 has out clicked you Player 2!");
                }       
            }
            //else if (status == PLAYER2_WON)
            {
                if(player == 1)
                {
                    jlblTitle.setText("Player 2 has out clicked you Player 1!");
                }
                if(player == 2)
                {
                    jlblTitle.setText("Congrats Player 2 you've out click Player 1!");
                }       
            }
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
      }
      /** This main method enables the applet to run as an application */
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        // Create a frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client");

        // Create an instance of the applet
        Client applet = new Client();
        applet.isStandAlone = true;

        // Get host
        if (args.length == 1) applet.host = args[0];

        // Add the applet instance to the frame
        frame.getContentPane().add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Invoke init() and start()
        applet.init();
        applet.start();

        // Display the frame
        frame.setSize(800, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
}
```